# Unable to run a js script using onClick property of js

Tags: javascript, python, express

I am trying to run a python script. I have an input field in html which will pass the values to js file. Then I used python-shell to pass the values in a form of arguments to the python script to execute them. I am using express.js for scripting

Here is my temp.ejs file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script  src="./index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./my_plot.png">
    <form>

    <input type="text" id="source" />
    <button  onclick="get_data();">Go!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
function get_data() {
  var source = document.getElementById("source").value;
  alert(source);

var options = {
   args: [source],
  pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python3'
};

var tests = new PythonShell('hello.py', options);
tests.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
  console.log(message);
}); 
}
```

python file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys

CHANNELS = 2
swidth = 4
Change_RATE = 2
T = int(sys.argv[1])

#print(source)
q = 0.5
Q = 1/10
A = 1 # amplitude of signal # quatization stepsize
N = 2000
spf = wave.open('sample.wav', 'rb')
RATE=spf.getframerate()
Byte = spf.getsampwidth()
signal = spf.readframes(1024)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int16')
def uniform_midtread_quantizer(x, Q):
    # limiter
    x = np.copy(x)

    idx = np.where(np.abs(x) >= 1)
    x[idx] = np.sign(x[idx])
    # linear uniform quantization
    xQ = Q * np.floor(x/Q + 1/2)

    return xQ

def plot_signals(x, xQ, T):
    e = xQ - x
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    plt.plot(signal, label=r'quantized signal $x_Q[k]$')
    plt.xlabel(r'$k$')
    plt.axis([0, N, -T, T])
    plt.grid()
    plt.savefig('my_plot.png')

# generate signal
x = signal
# quantize signal
xQ = uniform_midtread_quantizer(x, Q)
# plot signals
plot_signals(x, xQ, T)
```

When I am doing node index.js in terminal then I am getting the desired output but not when I pass the value through html (so no error with python and js file) 
Express.js is not causing the error as i have used vanilla ja also but same error occured

Comment: emmmm, I don't understand, where do You want to use this PythonShell, instance ? In Browser ? it's not possible. The instance created in browser cannot communicate with python interpreter, because browser API didn't expose IPC with client environment.

Comment: As @Take_Care_ states, the usual way to do this is to call a server (based on express.js if this is what you use) and the server runs the script. So the simpler is to pass it through a GET or POST request, even if the server runs locally..

Comment: @Kaddath so what should I exactly do now?

Comment: @Take_Care_ I have done exactly a same project in which on submitting the html form the data was passed to js and then to python script. I do not know why it is not working now..

Comment: @Take_Care_ as u said browser cannot communicate with python interpreter so if I use desktop app instead of browser will It work?

Comment: Btter do as @Kaddath proposed. Let the intepreter be on the backend side, but the input data will be coming with the POST request.